# remove raid0 from a dell t710 using perc

Tags: dell, dell-perc, raid0, raid

I got a dell server with 2 physical harddrives that are seen as one, because the system is utilizing raid0.

How do we disable this striping, such that we can see two different drives.
I'm well aware that this will cause all the data to be erased, and this isn't a problem, since we havent installed an os yet.

Thanks

EDIT:
Thanks for your replies, but I can't make this work, It looks like I'm only able to use the harddrive slots, if I'm using raid.

Answer (score 1):

During the boot sequence you will get a BIOS message about configuring the RAID array (if I remember right it's around when it enumerates the drives and it's Alt-A or Control-A, but I may be wrong on the keystrokes).

When you drop into the array configuration tool you will be able to delete the RAID container and re-create it (or configure the drives for pass-through) -- the tool is pretty self explanatory once you get into it :)

Comment: Hi, Could you elaborate on 'configure the drives for pass-through'
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Press F10 to go into the System Services.
From there you can deploy an OS.
Part of that service will allow you to reconfigure the RAID.